# How can I fix the uneven application of a text-underline hover effect (desktop users only - website not mobile-responsive yet)?

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, effects

I'm trying to create a sliding underline hover effect for my links using css only. The effect works so it's mostly successful but there's been an uneven application of the thickness of the underline that I want to fix but I'm not sure how.

I found a resource that instructed me to use the background-image linear gradient setting so that if the line spans multiple lines, the effect still works. That resource is here:

https://nerdcowboy.com/blog/sliding-underlined-links/

I'm using the third effect, which slides the underline in and out.

The site is not mobile-responsive yet so it will only appear right in a maximized desktop window. You can go through the page and hover over the links to see what I mean. Bear in mind, the site is still a work-in-progress. This is the web page:

https://sciencexfantasy.com/the-fundamentals-of-fiction-writing/

This is the css code I used for the effect:

```
article a, .widget a {
    color: #a90000;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
    background-size: 0% .1em;
    background-position-y: 100%;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-size 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

article a:hover, .widget a:hover, article a:focus, article a:active, .widget a:focus, .widget a:active {
    background-size: 100% 0.1em;
    background-position-x: 0%;
}
```

The resource suggested using 0.1em for the background height so that if the text size changes, it'll adjust. I've tried to correct this by using 2px, for example, but even that applies unevenly throughout the links in the page.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried to make it 2.5px?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried to do that as you suggested but it's the same problem. The line thickness is different from link to link. The odd thing is that it's distributed differently depending on what height I try to go with for the background size. One link ends up with the thin line with one setting and another link with the different size options. I'm not sure what's causing it. It's not the font because I have another website with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you will change the background-size, you need to change both in hover and the element itself.

Like this:

```
article a:hover, .widget a:hover {
    background-size: 100% 2.5px;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    line-height: 14.5px;
}
article a, article a:visited, .widget a, .widget a:visited {
    color: #a90000;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
    background-size: 0% 2.5px;
    background-position-y: 100%;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-size 0.2s ease-in-out;
    line-height: 14.5px;
}
```

It is most probably because of the font size. Most of your text height is `17.6px` and only the `Back to Top` link is `16.6px`. That's where I can see the difference. That is also the reason why I added a line height for both the element and the hover. If the above code does not work, try these:

1. Try changing the background-size `2.5px` to `0.2ch`
2. Try changing the line-height from `14.5px` to `1.8`

From what I have tested,
[image: test]

It works okay.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! It was a near-perfect fix to change it to .2ch and the line-height to 1.8 but there were a few links that were still to thick. I was wondering why the font sizes on your computer are different than the font sizes I set. The font size of the text that I set is 14.5px and the font size for the BACK TO TOP is 13px. Are you zoomed?

Comment: No, I did not zoomed it. Font size doesn't have anything to do with computers unless you view it in mobile phone. That's the only time font-size will vary if your website has responsive text. If you look at your inline style for the `p` tag of your BACK TO TOP, it is either hardcoded or some js is changing your font size to 13.5px. Double check your codes because the issue might be there somewhere.

Comment: I made a mistake in saying 13px for the BACK TO TOP. It is supposed to be 13.5px. The only thing is, you said it was 16.6px in your post. I'm not sure why that is. I'm a little confused about what you mean in terms of it varying. It shouldn't vary right? So why is it 16.6px when it should be 13.5px? Please bear with me, I'm still fairly new to this.

Comment: Oh. I was referring to the `height` of the element itself and not the `font-size`. Since the `weight` of the underline depends on the `font-size`, I checked the size of the elements as well and that's where the `16.6px` came from. Included in my post is "Most of your text height" and not `font-size`.